# VBAでRPAがしたいのでヒントをください

Tags: windows, excel, vba, winapi

windows API user32 から SendInput や SendMessage , FindWindow などを使って、VBAでExcelから他のアプリケーションソフト内にある複数のテキストボックスへコピペ作業を行おうと考えています。
ただし、
①貼り付け先ウィンドウがアクティブでなくても貼り付けが行われること
②コピペをしなければ他のアプリを操作していても問題ないこと
という条件を付けたいです。
コピペ作業では、テキストボックス間の移動に、
③Tabでの移動
④Ctrl+Tabでのタブ切り替え
⑤Ctrl+Alt+→でのリストボックス内移動
⑥Spaceでのボタン押下やチェックボックス切替、ラジオボタン切替
⑦矢印キーでのコンボボックスの値切替
⑧ボタン押下により出現したウィンドウへの移動、戻り
が必要です。
こんなことできるのでしょうか？ヒントとなるキーワードだけでも教えて頂ければ幸いです。
特に②を満たすのが難しいのと、⑥の方法を探しても空白文字の方法しか見つからない、⑤の3つ同時押しの情報が見つからないなど、困ってます。

Comment: VBAではなく、オープンソースでもない、個人作成のフリーソフトですが、こんなのがあります。ご参考に。[ウィンドウを操作しよう ウィンポス(=winpos=)紹介UWSCを超えるか!!](http://www002.upp.so-net.ne.jp/tinynealy/winpos.html)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/10887128.html

Comment: @htb マルチポストという言葉があったのですね。初めて知りました。お恥ずかしい。ご指摘に感謝します。既に投稿してしまった分に関しては、回答していただいた方がいらっしゃいますので、そのまま残させていただきます。

Comment: SOで禁止されていませんし何も消す必要はないですよ。回答する人に情報共有しているだけですので。

Answer (score 1):

自分ならwin32apiを使いたおしやすい他の言語（c,cpp,c#とか）でDLLを作りエクセルから呼ぶ
vba側はできるだけ、大まかな制御と、エクセルとのやりとりをするだけにする
vbaでwin32apiを駆使するのはシンドイかな、
細かい制御のネタはc言語系なら山盛りあると思います

Comment: DLLだと.dllファイルを.xlsmファイルと一緒に移動しなきゃならないのでしょうか、それだと一般ユーザーに利用してもらうには「煩わしい」と敬遠されそうです。それを恐れてDLLは手を付けたことがないです。良い方法があれば助言を頂けますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。